# NGRX/Data angular route guard - help waiting for data to load

Tags: ngrx, rxjs-observables

Angular 10, NGRX/Data 10

I have a route guard set up with the intent of loading all of my data before the getting to the page. I'm checking for a token in storage first, if no token - then redirect. If there is a token, check if the user data is loaded (the four dataService calls require user info to load). I want to wait until all four dataService calls are complete before allowing the guard to go to true.

I'm struggling with the Observables and how to wait for them to resolve. Here's what I have in the route guard.

```
userLoaded$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromState.getLoaded));

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (!this.authService.getToken()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.userLoaded$.pipe(
          tap(userLoaded => {
            if (!userLoaded) {
              this.store.dispatch(new GetUser({id: Number(this.authService.getUserId())}));
            }
          }),
          filter(userLoaded => !!userLoaded),
          tap( () => {
              this.typeDataService.getAll();
              this.groupDataService.getAll();
              this.routeDataService.getAll();
              this.officeDataService.getAll();
          })
      );
    }
  }
```

I really just don't have a good grasp on observables, pipes and subscriptions.

How do I set up the code to return an observable once all of the dataService calls have loaded the data?

Answer (score 0):

try to use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

or you can search for others operators [others operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators)